# Open this app to confirm your subscription before Jun 23, 2020

Tags: in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

Open this app to confirm your subscription before Jun 23, 2020. What is causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PurchaseResult was returning my purchases with acknowledge as false. Using the following code, managed to fix the issue.

```
for (Purchase purchase: purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()) {
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                        AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                .build();
                acknowledgePurchaseParams.getDeveloperPayload();

                AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
                        BillingResult billingResult1 = billingResult;
                    }

                };

                mBillingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
            }
```