# unable to reproduce account hold state for android subscription

Tags: android, google-play, subscription

Google have announced new state for subscription `account_hold`.It occurs if there were some problems when charging the user.
My aim is to test this state in my app.
There is [doc](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test) describes how to test different subsscription scenarios. Our app have subscription with no grace period.Which is exactly what the doc suggests ([Monthly subscription with account hold and no grace period](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test#expandable-1))
I do according to doc:

1. Sign up for an in-app subscription using your licensed test account
   and the payment method of "Test instrument always approves"
2. Go to the Account > Subscriptions section of the Google Play app,
   click your test subscription, and change payment method to "Test
   instrument, always declines"

When I do so my subscription doesn't enter in to `account_hold` state. Instead it's just becomes inactive on next recur.
How can I reproduce `account_hold` state for the subscription?

Answer (score 0):

for me, it was because I wasn't acknowledging the purchase. Using this answer fixed it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/62490569/8441431